# How to update values in third column using 2 columns values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to update the Column with 0 or 1, where for each empID the month is minimum and Sal Hike is Max:
I have written the code to find Min Month and Max Sal Hike for each employee.

```
df.sort_values(['salhike','month'],ascending=[False,True]).groupby("empid").head(1)
```

How can I update this in "Yes_or_No" with 1 col'n?

Input DF:

```
empid   age salhike month   YES_or_NO
123     23  12      1       0
123     23  24      2       0
123     23  87      3       0
123     23  35      4       0
111     23  87      1       0
111     23  35      2       0
111     23  14      3       0
111     23  12      4       0
```

I am trying to get output table is:

```
empid   age salhike month   YES_or_NO
123     23  12      1       0
123     23  24      2       0
123     23  87      3       1
123     23  35      4       0
111     23  87      1       1
111     23  35      2       0
111     23  14      3       0
111     23  12      4       0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try, using `sort_values`, then `duplicated` with subset on empid and convert boolean series to integer and `assign` back to column in dataframe:

<strike>df.assign(YES_or_NO = (~df.sort_values(['empid','salhike'])
                              .duplicated(subset='empid', keep='last')).astype(int))</strike>

```
df.assign(YES_or_NO = (~df.sort_values(['salhike','month'],
                                        ascending=['True','False','False'])
                          .duplicated(subset='empid', keep='last')).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
   empid  age  salhike  month  YES_or_NO
0    123   23       12      1          0
1    123   23       24      2          0
2    123   23       87      3          1
3    123   23       35      4          0
4    111   23       87      1          1
5    111   23       35      2          0
6    111   23       14      3          0
7    111   23       12      4          0
```

Comment: Trying  to apply this but  not working: file.assign(YES_or_NO = (~file.sort_values(['salhike','empid'], ascending=[False,True])
                          .duplicated(subset='empid', keep='last')).astype(int))

Comment: What sort or error or incorrect output are you getting?

Comment: I am getting smaller salhike and max month number as 1.

Comment: @subodhagrawal Try updated sort with month added into the sort.

Comment: file.assign(YES_or_NO = (~file.sort_values(['salhike','month'], ascending=[True,False])
                          .duplicated(subset='empid', keep='last')).astype(int))

Answer (score 3):

Using `groupby` `transform` `max`

```
df['YES_or_NO']=df.salhike.eq(df.groupby('empid')['salhike'].transform('max')).astype(int)
df
Out[380]: 
   empid  age  salhike  month  YES_or_NO
0    123   23       12      1          0
1    123   23       24      2          0
2    123   23       87      3          1
3    123   23       35      4          0
4    111   23       87      1          1
5    111   23       35      2          0
6    111   23       14      3          0
7    111   23       12      4          0
```

Update

```
df['YES_or_NO']=0
df.loc[df.groupby('empid')['salhike'].idxmax(),'YES_or_NO']=1
```

Comment: I am trying to get minimum month and max salhike.

Comment: @subodhagrawal what you mean min month with max salhike ? for id 123 min month is 1 and max value for it is 12 , so should we assign 1 to it ?

Comment: Your Code will give correct output but if, for EMPID 123, salhike is 87 for 4th month as well the this is giving me 1 1 for 3rd and 4th month both insted of only for 3rd month.

Comment: @subodhagrawal I given out the update , please check  it

Comment: Thanks...This on is easy :-)

Comment: @subodhagrawal yw:-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178373/discussion-between-subodh-agrawal-and-wen).